# CNN regression results in two distinct (incorrect) predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to solve a regression problem using a Python Keras CNN (Tensorflow as the backbone), where I try to predict a single y-value based on an 8-dimensional satellite image (23x45 pixels) that I have fetched from Google Earth Engine using their Python API. I currently have 280 images that I augment to get 2500 images using flipping and random noise. The data is normalized & standardized and I have removed outliers and images with only zeros.

I've tested numerous CNN-architecture, for example, this:
(Convolution2D(4,4,3),MaxPooling2D(2,2),dense(50),dropout(0.4),dense(30),dropout(0.4),dense(1)

This results in a weird behaviour where the predicted value is in mainly two distinct groups or clusters (where each group has very little variance). The true value has a much higher variance. See image below.

I have chosen not to publish any code snippets as my question is more of a general nature. What might lead to such clustered predictions? Are there any good common tricks to improve the results?
I've tried to solve the problem using a normal neural network and regression tools from SciKit-Learn, by flattening the images to one long array (length 23x45x8 = 8280). That doesn't result in clustering, although the accuracy is still quite low. I assume that is due to insufficient or inappropriate data.

[Plotted Truth (x) vs Prediction (y) which shows that the prediction is heavily clustered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4SII.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your model is quite simple, it cannot even properly extract feature, so i guess it is under fit. and your dropout is 40% in 2 layers, which quite high for such small network. you also have linear activation, it seems that way.

and yes number of sample can also have effect on group prediction, mostly class with majority of samples is chosen.

i have also noticed some of your truth values are greater than 1 and less than 0. you have to normalize properly and use proper activation function.

Comment: Thanks for some good ideas. I fixed the standardization, lowered the dropout and made the network much deeper with some improvement. I'm working on getting additional data, but I'm wondering if there are any good guides on what loss function and activation function to use? I got the best results so far with sigmoid activation for all dense layers and loss function mean_squared_logarithmic_error.

Comment: sigmoid is not used in deep learning, because it cause vanishing gradient, nor tanh is used. you have to use relu, leaky relu or dont other activation functions.

Comment: I see, that was helpful.